# creating expression subsituted into numbers in sage

Tags: expression, substitution, sage

It is common situation that creating symbolic expression for operation in sage, like `a+b =c`. Now subsequently as the variable `a` and `b` are known to be `a = 1` and `b = 2`, how can I create a expression(or only string) as `1+2=c`. Any answer will be appreciated. :-)

The followed is my scheme:

```
 var('a,b,c')
 c = a + b
 str(c)
 c(a=1,b=2)
```

Now the result is 'a+b' and 3. While I want to create dynamicly create strings as '1+2=c' after assign the value to `a` and `b`.

Edit: The original poster wants to know how to get a *string* that looks like `'1+2=c'` from `c=a+b` as a symbolic variable and substituting (somehow) `a=1` and `b=2`.  Sage typically automatically would add/simplify `1+2` to be `3`, and there is not really documentation about how to do this kind of thing, so this is a nontrivial question.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: By not providing anything, you'll get only down vote most of the time

Comment: This is actually not a bad question, but needs to be made clearer.

Comment: For example, I don't know how to do this without just using strings, and the OP wants it with symbolic variables.  Even `a.add(b,hold=True)` won't prevent the simplification once all elements are Sage `Integer`s.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Maybe I'm oversimplifying. If you already have values in your variables I don't see how to do it in a similar way.

```
var('a,b,c')
c = a + b
s = str(c)

su = {a: 1, b: 2}
for k in su.keys():
    s = s.replace(str(k),str(su[k]))
s
```